# Calculating a correlator

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, many-body, greens-functions

Consider a system of a quantum dot coupled to a metal (tunneling Hamiltonian approach). Creating and destroying electrons in the dot is done with the operators $c_{d\sigma}$ and $c^{\dagger}_{d\sigma}$, and $c_{k\sigma}$ and $c^{\dagger}_{k\sigma}$ in case of the metal (convention from the book by Bruus and Flensberg).

I am wondering how to calculate a time-independent correlator of the form
\begin{equation}
\langle d_{\sigma}c^{\dagger}_{k\sigma}\rangle,
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\langle A\rangle = \frac{1}{Z}\sum_{n}\langle n|A|n\rangle e^{-\beta E_n}.
\end{equation}
If a time-dependence would be involved, one could easily turn this into a lesser/greater Green's function, but for this correlator, I do not know how to proceed, as I do not have information about $|n\rangle$.